# Excel Macro not showing as add-in

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working with this excel macro since April 23rd. Recently it has stopped showing up even though it is showing installed. Any ideas?

What I have already tried:

- I have checked the trust center to add the folder I have the macro stored in but it is currently stored on an internal network drive that can not be added to the trust center.
- I have also moved the macro to the default directory for Macros. It still will not load in.
- When I just drag the macro .xla file into Excel it will pick it up and start showing in the VBA IDE, but only if the file I drag in is stored on the default directory.

Excel Macros installed:

[Excel Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpPX9.png)

[Add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skhlu.png)

Excel VBA IDE not showing the macros as well as not showing in the ribbon:

[Add-ins tab not showing add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Sbe.png)

[Missing from VBA IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFGpu.png)

Comment: Are you using a shared network drive to store it (I experienced somewhat similar issues in the past when using network drives)?

Comment: i just tried what you said and it showed????? do you know why????????

Comment: What exactly did you try? My problem with network drives was that the security settings for network drives prevented add-ins from loading.

Comment: I moved it to my desktop and it started to work. I'll have to reach out to IT so see if there is a security setting stopping my macro.

Comment: I added an answer - see if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain if this applies to your case, but this is what worked for me with the following set up:
- Using Windows
- Add-in stored on the network drive

My problem was that after I installed an add-in it would show up (both IDE and as a custom ribbon), but after I closed Excel and reopened it the add-in would fail to load (no ribbon, no IDE).

1. First step to fix this is to add a trusted location in Excel settings:
   Trust Center -> Trusted Locations
   You may need to select [Allow Trusted Locations on my network] before adding a location.
   You can add just one folder, or, if it is appropriate, you can even add the whole network drive.
   You may want to select [Subfolders in this location are also trusted]
2. The second step was far from obvious to me. I also needed to add network folder as a trusted location in **Internet Explorer** of all things:
   Settings -> Internet Options -> Security -> Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced
   Then you need to add the folder path to the network folder that contains the add-in.

After completing both steps and reopening Excel add-ins in the network folder started to appear both in IDE and as a custom ribbon. These two steps were necessary part of installation for every user.

If you are using multiple add-ins you may want to consider using one network folder for them. You can also take a look at this  [question about network add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50473365/8597922) to see how they can be distributed in a more convenient fashion (one of the answers there is mine).

Comment: thank you that was able to fix it and keep it on my network drive. I'm assuming my IT department did something without telling us (again). I was able to do just step 1 and it worked for me :)