# excel vba: save (and overwite existing) a read only file

Tags: excel, vba

Ive run into a bit of a roadblock

What im trying to do, is when you click a button in the workbook, it saves a read-only version to a network folder, overwriting if necessary (it will be) the idea here is end users can only open the workbook in read-only so the file is not locked and can be updated as necessary by the person with the master-file open, though they wont see the updates until it reopens

is there a way of setting file attributes to a not-open file so it can be set not-read-only as part of the macro before the copy, or is there a way to overwrite a read only file?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474925/8597922) to a similar question. In this answer a read-only workbook is replaced by a new version of a read-only workbook. It seems like what you are looking after. Although it is tailored for an `.xlam` file it should work for any other excel workbook.

Comment: Although the question is about an add-in with development copy you can apply it to any other workbook with master-file. You would still make use of the same `SetAttr` calls changing file to read-write, replacing it and changing its attribute to read-only again.